# Android Studio freezes on startup

Tags: android, sdk, loading, freeze

I searched all day but haven't find a solution yet.

Today I installed Android Studio without any problems.
I added the correct path.

```
JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
```

and

```
JDK_HOME  to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
```

But, when I start the program it freezes on the loading screen. (The gray picture with the green android logo and text Android Studio)
It does create a process that I can't close, but after waiting for 20 minutes it's still on that screen.

I tried a clean install, also I tried the 32bit version without any success because it complained about the jvm that I could not fix for some reason.
I also did an update for it, but without success.

I have no idea what else I can try to fix this, but I also don't see myself going back to eclipse.

Comment: Try using java 1.7 or 1.6 instead

Comment: Oke i tryed older versions but still gave the same problem.

Comment: Are you running on Windows/Mac or Linux?

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction i had some stuff to deal with. So after a full reinstall of my windows the problems seems to be vanished. I still don't know why it happened though.

Comment: I did this from the command line: adb kill-server (then) adb start-server and that unfroze Android Studio at startup for me.

Comment: needing to reinstall Windows is not a solution!

Answer (score 30):

What worked for me was to disconnect my android phone which was connected to the computer(in the debugging mode).

Comment: My computer was shut down by a power cut overnight whilst in suspend mode. When I rebooted the next day Android Studio would not load as per the OP description. This suggestion appeared to fix the hang at startup issue I was experiencing, though the circumstances are somewhat different. As with people above I find this a very odd bug...

Answer (score 10):

I went from 1.5 to 2.0 and after updating it wouldn't load (hung at the startup screen). I had to delete the .android folder, the android.15 folder and the .AndroidStudioPreview2.0 folder under user. I also had to rename the SDK folder and after it started up I rename it back to what it was. Which means I had to add the path back to android studio. This was the only way I got it to work.

Comment: I've done all of those, but no avail. *then* I restarted my Mac after doing those and then it worked. a restart was necessary in my case, dunno why.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue. "Run as administrator" helped me.

Comment: This personally didn't fix it for me, but it may do for some people.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution comes from [JLund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504476/jlund) (from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450221/android-studio-freezes-on-startup-fixed#comment43881864_25450221)):

> I did this from the command line:
>
> ```
> adb kill-server
> adb start-server
> ```
>
> and that unfroze Android Studio at startup for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` or the like defined as you environment variable. You might need to uninstall any Android SDK previously installed manually after removing those environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

My Android Studio auto loads the last worked-on project.
I cancelled the loading project before the IDE hung.
The Android Studio launcher comes up.  Select the "Open an existing..." option.

Windows 10

Java 1.8.0_131

Android Studio 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio kept getting hung up on a white screen before the IDE loaded any buttons. I renamed the project that it was trying to load, restarted Android Studio, and selected another project and it loaded correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I had to revamp all manually installed 'HOME' environments and start it again-

Comment: i mean i had to remove them in my case