# Android Studio won't finish loading

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my Android Studio and since the update, it will load to about 80% and then just freeze. It won't give an error and it will just never load no matter how long you wait. I have tried uninstalling and redownloading along with other various things but nothing seems to be working any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDHQx.png)

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the folder for windows

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.AndroidStudio4.0
```

and for MAC

```
/Users/YOURNAME/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your phone if it is connected to the computer.
It may sound strange, but I had a similar situation.

Also, you can have a look at this post: [Android Studio freezes on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450221/android-studio-freezes-on-startup)

Comment: There is no device connected and no virtual device running