# Android studio freezes after updating to version 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have not used Andriod studio for about 5 years. I want to catch up a bit on Kotlin. So yesterday I have updated my Android studio from 1.4 to 4.1.2.But the gray bar on the bottom on start-up freezes at around 90%. I have waited for a couple of hours but it just freeze there.

[image]

My OS: Windows 10;
I have tried

- [Android Studio freezes after updating to 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024513/android-studio-freezes-after-updating-to-2-0)
- [Android Studio freezes on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450221/android-studio-freezes-on-startup)
- [Cannot start Android Studio. Android Studio stuck at the splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819064/cannot-start-android-studio-android-studio-stuck-at-the-splash-screen/29819261)

I have also tried to uninstall Android Studio completely and install it from scratch.
I have restarted my pc several times.
I have also tried to install version 4.1. It freezes around 90% too.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues this link will surely help you out

Comment: Thanks Usama for ur link. It works for me by deleting the following folder. 
<q>
Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio<version>
Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1
</q>

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65662719/3316928

> Delete Folder This Folder
>
> **For Windows:** C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1
>
> **For MacOS:** ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Comment: Works with the version ``Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4``